# Performing grep, awk in perl

Tags: perl, file, awk, grep

I need to perform the following task in perl script

`'cat $temp_file | grep $specific_word | awk '{ print \$2 }'`

```
open(F,$temp_file);
@list=<F>;close F;
$specific_word ="String I want";
@f=grep /$specific_word/,@list;
print $f[2];
```

I am doing the above. Can someone help me with this. Is there any alternate way to do this?

**Note: I need to print the second word of each grepped line. By the above code, I am getting only the second line.**

Comment: Perl supports regex natively, I don't think using external tools will give you the best results.

Comment: And what happens when you run your code?  Please visit the [help] and read [ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.

Comment: @JimGarrison edited the question

Comment: Just as an aside, the command line you are starting with is awful. You virtually never need to use `grep` and `awk` in the same pipeline, not to mention `cat`. That should simply read: `awk '/specific_word/ {print $2}' temp_file`.

Comment: @MichaelVehrs yes it is.. but all I need is to do it in a perl way

Comment: [edit] your question to show a [mcve] including concise, testable sample input and expected output. See [ask].

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -lane "print \$F[1] if /$specific_word/" $temp_file
```

If you really want to be verbose (make sure you `use 5.12.0` (or similar) to get `say`:

```
open my $f, '<', $temp_file;

while(<$f>) {
        my @F = split;
        say $F[1] if /$specific_word/;
}
```

Comment: I need to use it in my script

Comment: @VinodiniNatrajan you should figure it out on your own now.

Comment: @VinodiniNatrajan The `use v5.10;` or `use feature 'say';` at the top of the script gives you  the ability to do `say "hello"`, instead of `print "hello\n"`

Comment: I think you can skip the use of `@F` entirely by just `print +(split)[1] if m/$specific_word/`. It might be worth `quotemeta` or `\Q\E` depending on the source of `$specific_word` too, as adding a broken regex from user input can lead to all sorts of wierdness.